# Django How to select differrnt table based on input?

Tags: django, django-models, backend

I have searched for the solution to this problem for a long time, but I haven't got the appropriate method.

Basically All I have is tons of tables, and I want to query value from different tables using raw SQL.

In Django, we need a class representing a table to perform the query, for example:

```
Routes.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM routes")
```

In this way, I can only query a table, but what if I want to query different tables based on the user's input?

I'm new to Django, back in ASP.NET we can simply do the following query:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM " + county + " ;";
var bus = _context.Database.SqlQuery<keelung>(query).ToList();
```

Is this case, I can do the query directly on the database instead of the model class, and I can select the table based on the user's selection.

Is there any method to achieve this with Django?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)?

Comment: Thanks a lot!, I thought it is not what im looking for lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run raw queries in Django like this -

```
From django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
table = my_table;
cursor.execute("Select * from " + table)
data = cursor.fetchall()
```